# Change Azure SQL Server Collation

Tags: azure-sql-database, collation

We are trying to put our DB in sql azure and we are running into an issue.  We have a stored procedure that is of collation **Latin1_General_CI_AI** and in there is does some joins with **sys.objects** which appears to have a collation of **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**.  When we try to create the stored procedure we get the error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

We were able to create the stored procedure by adding **COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** at the end of the **sys.object** join but we have multiple places where sys.object is used and I've also read that temp tables might have the same problem.

So my questions is, is there a way to change the collation on the "server", I can't see anything when creating a new **SQL Server (logical server)**.  It would save us the trouble to force the collation everywhere.

Comment: If you want to change the collation on your database you should create a ticket. The support team will do it for you within reasonable time.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this using bacpac.

1. Export the database using "Export Data-tier Application" in management studio
2. Make a copy of the bacpac
3. Rename the copy by changing the extension to .zip
4. Open the zip by and open the model.xml file ( use 7-zip to open zip then double click to open the xml in notepad. Edit and save )
5. Change Property Name="Collation" Value="Latin1_General_CS_AS"
6. Rename the zip back to bacpac
7. The bacpac does contain a checksum that it uses to validate the package.  This needs to be updated.  Fortuntately there is a git copy of the [dacchksum.exe](https://github.com/gertd/dac/tree/master/drop/debug) utility.  Simply run against the new bacpac in order to get the checksum value.
8. Rename the bacpac back to zip
9. Inside the zip, open the origin.xml and update the checksum
10. Rename the zip back to bacpac
11. Try the import again!

Comment: Just a clarification on step 7 use "Calculated" and not "Stored" and it works perfectly!

Comment: Instead of zipping and using dacchksum.exe run this script
$modelXmlPath = "path2model\model.xml"
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider")
$fileStream = new-object System.IO.FileStream ` -ArgumentList @($modelXmlPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$hash = $hasher.ComputeHash($fileStream)
$hashString = ""
Foreach ($b in $hash) { $hashString += $b.ToString("X2") }
$fileStream.Close()
$hashString
update Orgin.xml and zip
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/08/16/editing-a-bacpac-file/

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it is not possible to change the collation for an existing Azure SQL Database. You however **can** specify the collation at the point when database is created. 
In case you are doing create via Azure Portal, you will see the Collation option in the Create dialogue. See some details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/#create-a-new-azure-sql-database

Answer (score 2):

Following is the command-line based procedure that Microsoft tech support led me through to export, modify, and create a new database using [sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download). This method worked, whereas an equivalent process using SSMS resulted in error 842.

1. Export: `sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:{database-server}.database.windows.net /sdn:{database} /su:{user-name} /sp:{password} /tf:{local-bacpac-path}`
2. Rename the `.bacpac` file to instead end in `.zip`.
3. Extract from the zip `model.xml` and `Origin.xml`.
4. In `model.xml`, edit `DataSchemaModel/Model/Element[Type="SqlDatabaseOptions"]/Property[Name="Collation"]`.
5. Save the script below to `hash.ps1` and from PowerShell, run `hash.ps1`. When prompted specify the path to `model.xml`. The script with print the hash for `model.xml`.
6. In `Origin.xml`, update `DacOrigin/Checksums/Checksum[Uri="/model.xml"]` with the new hash.
7. Update the zip with the updated `model.xml` and `Origin.xml` files.
8. Rename the zip file back to again end in `.bacpac`.
9. Import: `sqlpackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:{database-server}.database.windows.net /tdn:{database} /tu:{user-name} /tp:{password} /sf:{local-bacpac-path} /p:DatabaseEdition=Standard /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=S1`

   In place of `Standard` and `S1`, use the database edition and service objective that matches your workload.

---

#### hash.ps1

```bsh
$modelXmlPath = Read-Host "model.xml file path"
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider")
$fileStream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList @($modelXmlPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$hash = $hasher.ComputeHash($fileStream)
$hashString = ""
Foreach ($b in $hash) { $hashString += $b.ToString("X2") }
$fileStream.Close()
$hashString
```